# glColor3f Only Colors Red

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have a weird problem in `OpenGL` with `glColor3f`. In the code below, if I change the red value of `glColor3f`, then the polygon below will turn into that shade of red. However, if I change green or blue, then it somehow doesn't change the color of the polygon, but it changes the color of all the other objects in the game. Basically, only the red value of the function works, and I need the blue and green to work too.

```
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
for(int i = 0; i < totalhumans; i++)
{
    if(humans[i].rage)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(humans[i].x,humans[i].y,humans[i].depth);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex3f(-16.0f,-(humans[i].dimen->bodyh/2)-16,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(-16.0f,-(humans[i].dimen->bodyh/2)-8,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(16.0f,-(humans[i].dimen->bodyh/2)-8,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(16.0f,-(humans[i].dimen->bodyh/2)-16,0.0f);
            glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

This is my initialization code:

```
void START_GAME()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_TIMER);
    Mix_OpenAudio(22050,MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT,2,2048);
    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
    loadsettings();
    if(fullscreen)
    {
        const SDL_VideoInfo *VideoInfo = SDL_GetVideoInfo();
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(VideoInfo->current_w, VideoInfo->current_h, 32, SDL_OPENGL|SDL_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    if(!fullscreen)
    {
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_OPENGL);
    }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.0f);

    setvariables();
    loadimages();
    loadsounds();

    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Freshmen Stuffing Boys",NULL);
    SDL_WM_SetIcon(badge,NULL);

    running = true;
}
```

EDIT: I found out that for some reason, after disabling `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, the color I wanted appeared. Can someone explain why that is so?

This question is not a duplicate because 1) my computer is new, and all of it's graphics drivers are new, so it wasn't a gpu problem, and 2) I'm writing the code for the first time, so I have no idea if the code would work on any other computers.

Comment: It seems that there are some problems on initializing openGL.

Comment: From the link above: "_Solved.. it was indeed a gpu issue, I got the drivers from the manufacturer and it is now working properly... go figure_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you have, in other code, enabled texturing. When this polygon is drawn, GL will use the last used texture and texture coordinate (as you haven't told it otherwise), and in your case this is probably a red pixel. As a result, your vertex colour is being modulated by red, resulting in the blue and green values being multiplied by zero.

If you don't want texturing, disable it. If you do want it, set up the right texture and provide texture coordinates.